# E2E test Code coverage for the application using Playwright in .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, playwright, playwright-test, playwright-dotnet

I have E2E testing using playwright in . NET core 6 application. Is there any way to get the report for code coverage.

There is a way for JS application https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-coverage

Using the package https://www.npmjs.com/package/playwright-test-coverage

Is there anything available for .net?

Comment: Are you looking for this?
https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/release-notes#html-report-update

Comment: No I am looking for code coverage for test cases similar to this https://github.com/anishkny/playwright-test-coverage-demo

Comment: @Zephire is that report generator support in .NET core

Comment: it should be as it's straight from the dotnet docs of playwright.

Comment: @Zephire There is no documentation for Code coverage for dotnet